# Render svg content Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have static svg file inside my images folder. I'd like to render actual svg content inside my anchor tag. I tried `{% static "images/blog/facebook-icn.svg" %}` and it just parse it as a string. what is the function to render actual content of svg file inside html?

The code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

   <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=my-site{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}"
      target="_blank" class="facebook">
      {% static "images/blog/facebook-icn.svg" %}
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem loading svg files directly from `static`. One solution is to place it in the `templates` directory and the using it with `{% include 'logo.svg' %}`.

An alternate and easy we to approach this is to directly use the `django-inline-svg` module.

`pip install django-inline-svg`

Answer (score 0):

Do this and after give thumbs up, please (DO NOT USE IMG TAG, it's terrible to use css after).

The easiest and rightest way ever:

1 - Download the svg files (put them into svg folder) and sprite file, like this (Note that "sprite.svg" is not in svg folder, but img folder, be aware:

[image]

2 - In your template file:

```
{% load static %}

<svg class="search__logo">
      <use xlink:href="{% static 'shop/img/sprite.svg' %} #icon-magnifying-glass"></use>
</svg>
```

#icon-magnifying-glass is the "id" of the svg i've choosen within sprite.svg file.

I tested thousands of libraries, but this is a natural way you can use your svgs without having to reinvent wheel.

Long life!